# How to install skype in xubuntu 14.04 LTS 64 bit

Tags: xubuntu, 64-bit, skype, 14.04

I am trying to install skype in xubuntu 14.04 64bit from [here](http://www.skype.com/en/download-skype/skype-for-computer/). I tried `ubuntu 10.04 32bit` and `ubuntu 12.04(multiarch)`. In xubuntu 14.04 64bit for both cases it is showing broken package message. Could any one give me a solution of this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try to install it with `gdebi`. In case it is simply an issue with missing dependencies, it should grab the necessary packages and install them. Type

```
sudo gdebi PACKAGENAME.deb
```

within a terminal in the directory of the `.deb` file you downloaded from that link.

Comment: Thank you. I was using `gdebi` from the first time. I downloaded deb file, and try to install, but the broken package message was there.

Comment: Perhaps add the messages you get?

Comment: This is the error I got http://postimg.org/image/ix6eajt4n/